# How can I make Pysolfc stay resized?

Tags: 10.10, window-management

I'm setting up Ubuntu for my grandfather, and he really likes Solitaire. I'm using Pysolfc because of its *Vegas-style* scoring, which other Linux solitaire apps don't have.

However, whenever I resize the window, and then close and start it again, it doesn't keep the dimensions I previously set.

Is there any way to set the dimensions through a command, or by doing some fancy X stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wmctrl` is such a package which will resize windows that are open.

The following is a quick - but not really elegant - way to launch and resize an application.

Create a file using your favourite text editor and add the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
easytag &
sleep 5
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,-1,-1,1200,800
```

Obviously change "easytag" for your application you which to launch and change "1200,800" for the width and height of your application.

The script launches the application then sleeps for 5 seconds to allow enough time for the application to open.  Then wmctrl resizes the active window - which should be the newly opened application.

Add an execute permission on the file

```
chmod +x
```

you can now run the new executable from - for example - a launcher on the desktop.